# How to begin with a paragraph in latex

Tags: indentation

I am writing my B.Sc. report. Here I have write a part  of introduction. but the problem is I want begin the sentences with a gap like...
 **[image]

Answer (score 13):

Don't do that! Anyway, you may need `indentfirst` package

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As I commented, it is somewhat of a typographical standard that the first paragraph following a sectioning name is **not** indented.

However, one can overcome that with `\hspace*{\parindent}`, which I have macro-fied as `\indentthis`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand\indentthis{\hspace*{\parindent}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction} 
\indentthis Blah blah is indented.

This will be auto-indented.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: better to use indentfirst I think, rather than having to find all these again if you change your mind about the document style.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree.  I therefore have macro-fied it so that the macro can be nullified if desired.

Comment: but you still miss the opportunity to use indentfirst: a package with impeccable  heritage and the highest documentation-to-code ratio of any package on ctan:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle LOL, no doubt.  I was very tempted to plagiarize the answer of JouleV just so that I, too, could employ this exquisite package.  But, at the last, my conscience got the better of me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your package is simply the most understandable LaTeX package